# Python request gives 415 error while post data

Tags: python, python-requests, http-status-code-415

I am getting 415 error while posting data to server. This is my code how can i solve this problem. Thanks in advance!

```
import requests
import json
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
#headers = {'content-type':'application/javascript'}
#headers={'content-type':'application/json', 'Accept':'application/json'}
url = 'http://IPadress/kaaAdmin/rest/api/sendNotification'
data = {"name": "Value"}
r = requests.post(url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth('shany.ka', 'shanky1213'),json=data)
print(r.status_code)
```

Comment: yes i have done but same as well as previous respond it error 415.

Answer (score 37):

According to [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/415),

> The HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type client error response code
> indicates that the server refuses to accept the request because the
> payload format is in an unsupported format.
>
> The format problem might be due to the request's indicated
> Content-Type or Content-Encoding, or as a result of inspecting the
> data directly.

In your case, I think you've missed the headers.
Uncommenting

```
headers={
    'Content-type':'application/json', 
    'Accept':'application/json'
}
```

and including `headers` in your `POST` request:

```
r = requests.post(
    url, 
    auth=HTTPBasicAuth('shany.ka', 'shanky1213'),
    json=data,
    headers=headers
)
```

should do the trick

---

```
import requests
import json
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth


headers = {
    'Content-type':'application/json', 
    'Accept':'application/json'
}
url = 'http://IPadress/kaaAdmin/rest/api/sendNotification'
data = {"name": "Value"}

r = requests.post(
    url, 
    auth=HTTPBasicAuth('shany.ka', 'shanky1213'), 
    json=data, 
    headers=headers
)
print(r.status_code)
```

Comment: Being a newbie to Python, I've been confused with json x data parameter difference, i kept receiving 415 while using data parameter to send the body. Using json parameter solves the issue, and you don't even need to send the content type header.

Comment: I get the same error and post it as a new question here:    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67936078/python-request-gives-415-error-while-post-data-unless-data-keyvalue  and the solution is the same too.  i have to add `data={"key,"value"}` to make it work, even though `data` is an optional keyword according to the docs.

Comment: I've also encountered the same issue. Thank you for help.

Comment: Hi @Giorgos, can you please tell how can I access the "data" sent in "json=data".

Answer (score 4):

As a workaround, try hitting your api using Postman. When you can successfully hit the api in postman, generate python code in postman (button is present in the top right corner). You can copy the code in your python project.

Comment: Postman actually gives you good code. I ran into the same issue but I followed this, then got my issue sorted. Here's a link to see how to get code from postman https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4XxcBI2uViA

Answer (score 1):

Another possible cause is using requests.post when you should be using requests.get or vice versa. I doubt that this is a common problem, but in my case a server that was happy to accept an HTTP GET for a search rejects it with a 415 when HTTP POST is used instead.  (Yet another site required that a search be requested using HTTP POST.  It was reusing that code that caused my problem.)